# Python add 2 multidimensional numpy arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to collect/concat multiple `numpy` arrays in a single numpy array. I can do this with `pandas` data frame as:

```
df_train = pd.DataFrame()
... loop ...:
    df_temp = pd.read_json(file)
    df_train = pd.concat([df_train, df_temp], ignore_index=True, axis=0, sort=False)
```

in a loop. With this I'm able to combine various data in a single data frame.

What I want to do this is with numpy arrays. I tried the same thing as:

```
nump_train = np.nan
... loop ...:
    nump = df_temp.values
    nump_train = np.concatenate((nump_train, nump))
```

but I cannot concat zero-dimensional arrays as the error message says (ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated)

How can I do this like in pandas?

ps: I can solve this with a bad-written hard-coded code as:

```
w=1
for loop:
    if w == 1:
        nump1 = sc.transform(df_temp.drop(['time'], axis=1))
    elif w == 2:
        nump2 = sc.transform(df_temp.drop(['time','trend'], axis=1))
    elif w == 3:
        nump3 = sc.transform(df_temp.drop(['time'], axis=1))
    w += 1
X_train = np.concatenate((nump1, nump2, nump3), axis = 0)
```

Bu this bad coding and I cannot scale this in a loop.

EDIT 1:

Actual code is this:

```
w = 1

for i in range(1, loop_size+1):

    df_train = pd.DataFrame()
    nump_train = np.nan

    random_list = random.sample(file_list, selection)

    for json in random_list:
        json_name = json[:json.index('_')]
        df_temp = pd.read_json(filedir + json)

        train_period_mask = (df_temp['time'] > train_start_date) & (df_temp['time'] < train_end_date)

        df_temp = df_temp.loc[train_period_mask]
        df_temp.index = np.arange(0, len(df_temp))


        df_temp = calc_(df_temp)
        df_temp['trend'] = zg(df_temp, zg_ratio)
        df_temp['trend_shifted'] = df_temp.trend.shift(-1)
        df_temp = df_temp.dropna()

        nump = sc.fit_transform(df_temp.drop(['time','trend_shifted','trend'], axis=1))

        if w == 1:
            nump1 = sc.transform(df_temp.drop(['time','trend_shifted','trend'], axis=1))
        elif w == 2:
            nump2 = sc.transform(df_temp.drop(['time','trend_shifted','trend'], axis=1))
        elif w == 3:
            nump3 = sc.transform(df_temp.drop(['time_period_start','trend_shifted','trend'], axis=1))

        df_train = pd.concat([df_train, df_temp], ignore_index=True, axis=0, sort=False)
        nump_train.append(nump)
        w += 1

    drop_list = ['time_period_start']
    df_train.drop(drop_list, 1, inplace = True )


    start = timeit.default_timer()
    sc = MinMaxScaler()
    X_train = sc.fit_transform(df_train.drop(['trend','trend_shifted'], axis=1))
    X_train2 = np.concatenate((nump1, nump2, nump3), axis = 0)
    y_train = df_train['trend_shifted'].values
```

I want X_train and X_train2 to have the same shape.

Comment: Some example input and desired output data would be helpful.

Comment: `np.concatenate` expects same dimensions for all inputs. If you are appending a 0 dimensional array, use `np.append`. If the array can be zero dimensional or several items, you can use  `np.concatenate((nump_train, np.atleast_1d(nump)))`

Comment: @Mstaino I triend `nump_train.append(nump)` but gave me `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'append'` error

Comment: @NilsWerner I added some code

Comment: Stay away from `np.append`..All i does is tweak the the input dimensions a bit and call concatenate.  Don't use any repeatedly in a loop.  Collect arrays in a list and concatenate just once.

Comment: @hpaulj I collected all arrays in a list just now and concatenated them at once as you suggested and it finally worked. Please write it in an answer so that I can accept it

Comment: You do need to pay attention to dimensions when concatenating.  A scalar becomes a 0d array, and can't be concatenated with another array on a nonexistant axis.

Comment: @hpaulj All my different data have the same shape (2x2). Columns have the same size but rows have different sizes. I managed to concetane as per your suggestion.